# Merging [bullet] and [bulletphysics] tags

Tags: feature-request, retag-request

Please merge [bullet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/bullet) (282 questions) and [bulletphysics](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/bulletphysics) (203 questions).

I just figure that few minutes ago while posting a new question.

both tags have word to word the same description.

Comment: One problem is that [bullet] is also incorrectly used for many questions about *bullet points* in some UI. This would take a lot of editing to fix.

Comment: I've looked through the [bullet] tagged questions and retagged incorrect ones. Now it should be quite fine for merging.