# Should we shoot the [bullet]?

Tags: discussion, burninate-request, retag-request, tag-disambiguation

The tag [bullet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/bullet) refers to questions regarding bullet physics as it says in the description. However, people use it for all sorts of things such as bullet points, calculations of game bullets/projectiles etc. The tag [bulletphysics](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/bulletphysics) is much more clear and therefore [bullet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/bullet) could be burninated. If you need examples of tag misuse, I can provide some.

Any arguments against this?

Comment: It seems like the tag is referring to a [specific library](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/bullet/info) , it would be good with some examples, consider this meta post if you edit your request http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/239190/when-to-burninate/239191#239191

Comment: Whew. Is [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/41838138/2564301) using the Bullet library, or is it just used as a generic name for a variable?

Comment: @RadLexus: BulletPhysics is developed in C++. So pretty sure this is a generic name for a projectile.

Comment: @PetterFriberg: I am constantly editing bullet out of non-related posts. I just feel that a duplicate tag for the same thing is not helpful, especially when the one with less clarity is misused often. I will read the meta post and update.

Comment: @RadLexus No, it's using pure Sprite-Kit, so I edited it to be tagged `[projectile]` instead of `[bullet]` as the `[bullet]` tag description recommends.

Comment: Title: _"Bite the [bullet]"_.

Comment: Came to propose a Title change, but @Cerbrus beat me to it. ;)

Comment: @Ben I know your frustration, Rad Lexus has a [nice solution](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/342233/5292302), I will volunteer to edit and cv off-topic questions if Rad's solution get some meta consensus, it can be nice break in software-engineering

Comment: Why do I get random down-votes? Was my request that inappropriate? :) I only take this as some joke on "If you have counterarguments, fire away". As long as it does not backfire...

Comment: They aren't "random". You posted a [burninate-request], and people downvote those when they disagree with your request. Yes, I think the request was inappropriate, but I didn't leave a comment of my own because other comments have already adequately expressed my concerns. The tag isn't as useless as you make it out to be and shouldn't be burninated because it refers to a specific library.

Comment: Oh, I did not know that this is done that way in meta. This is my first post and I interpreted it likea remark to a badly written question as it is in topic branches of stackoverflow. Thanks for the explanation.

Comment: Alternative title suggestion: [bullet] time

Comment: related: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/290014/merging-bullet-and-bulletphysics-tags

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The single word *bullet* does not make it clear enough it should be used unambiguously for the Bullet library. The tag description contains "do not use this for ... (an extensive list follows)".

In addition,

> Bullet is an Open Source collision detection and rigid body dynamics library ...

and other libraries *do* have a `-library` suffix. Also note the imperative "The" in front of the library names:

> `python-imaging-library`: The Python Imaging Library (née `PIL`) provides ...
>
> `portable-class-library`: The Portable Class Library project enables you to ...
>
> `android-design-library`: The Design package provides APIs to ...

or indicate in another way that the library name is not a generic name for a certain class of objects:

> `google-closure-library`: a JavaScript framework that ...
>
> `enterprise-library`: a collection of application blocks and core infrastructure ...

There is no practical use for a standalone tag named `[bullet]`. I propose to shoot that `[bullet]` and change the library tag to `bullet-library`.

Comment: I am ok with this, sounds like a good idea. Additionally, could somebody add a tag synonym for it then which is [bulletphysics]? They are basically the same tag. I do not know if merging would be another solution.

Comment: In fact, the tag should be [bulletphysics-library] since that is the library's name: http://bulletphysics.org/wordpress/

Comment: @Ben Shouldn't it be [bullet-physics-library] then?

Comment: @Ben "In fact, the tag should be [bulletphysics-library] since that is the library's name" -- That feels unnecessary. Both the blog posts in the page you linked to and the [readme on GitHub](https://github.com/bulletphysics/bullet3) refer to it as "Bullet" in most places. [bullet-library] should be read as "The library called Bullet", and not as a transcription of the full name of the library.

Comment: Isn't the library postfix unnecessary then? If the name of the library is "bulletPhysics" then that could just be the tag without the "library". That being said, the website uses all three combinations (Bullet, Bullet Physics, Bullet Physics Library)!

Comment: @code11: for *some* consistency, I'd rather see `-library` appended. See the other, non-ambiguous, tags in my examples. And if we decide to do so **today**, for consistency's sake, we have some leverage for similar requests.

Comment: ´-library´ in any case sounds great to me for consistency. [bulletphysics-library] or [bullet-physics-library] would be my first choices since that includes that it is a physics library and because even the logo says bullet physics library. bullet is usually just an abbreviation (I am an active moderator of the bullet physics forum and contributor to the library). But I am also ok with [bullet-library] if this is simplifying the discussion.

Comment: Enterprise Library has/had the "library" in the name, so it might not be the best example for consistently appending `-library`...